# Property or method "LIVE" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue.js  in laravel to update my scorecard every thing was working fine until i don't apply check for only update scorecard of Live matches. Here is my code.

```
<script>
export default {
  data: function(){
    return {
      scoreCard: "",
      play: ""
    };
  },
  props: ["live_check","playingteamid","series_id", "match_id"],
  methods: {
    getScoreCard: function(s, m, p) {
      fetch(
        "https://api_Request" +
          s +
          "/" +
          m +
          "?format=json"
      )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(data.fullScorecard.innings[0].team.id==p){
                this.play = data.fullScorecard.innings[0];
            }else if(typeof data.fullScorecard.innings[1] !='undefined'){
              if(data.fullScorecard.innings[1].team.id==p){
              this.play = data.fullScorecard.innings[1];
              }
          }
        });
    }
  },
  created: function(){
      this.getScoreCard(this.series_id,this.match_id,this.playingteamid);
      if(this.live_check=='LIVE'){ //This Live check is showing error

          setInterval(function(){
              this.getScoreCard(this.series_id,this.match_id,this.playingteamid);
          }.bind(this),3000)
      }else{
          console.log('Match is not Live');
      }
  }
};
</script>
```

*vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Property or method "LIVE" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
(found in )*

Comment: Are you using it in html markup?

Comment: <live-score-card :live_check='{!!$matchData->match->status!!}' :playingteamid='{!!$playingTeamId!!}' :series_id='{!!$series_id!!}' :match_id='{!!$match_id!!}'></live-score-card>
I am using it in laravel blade template
its the part of vue component